# Filter multidimensional array by lowest price

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-filter

I'm working with an array that I'd like to filter so it only contains the lowest prices per key. So 50 would only have one unit, same with 100, and that unit would be the lowest price.

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
$units = [
    50 => [
        41788 => ['StdRate' => 231.0000, 'UnitName' => "NN23"],
        46238 => ['StdRate' => 303.0000, 'UnitName' => "1038"],
        46207 => ['StdRate' => 303.0000, 'UnitName' => "1007"]
    ],
    100 => [
        41570 => ['StdRate' => 299.0000, 'UnitName' => "HH18"],
        46214 => ['StdRate' => 388.0000, 'UnitName' => "1014"]
    ]
];
```

I wanted to avoid doing this with a complicated foreach loop, so I thought an `array_filter` would be nice, but having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Or would a `foreach` be best?

```
$filtered = array_filter($units, function($a) {

});
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    50 => [
        41788 => ['StdRate' => 231.0000, 'UnitName' => "NN23"]
    ],
    100 => [
        41570 => ['StdRate' => 299.0000, 'UnitName' => "HH18"]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't put all those elements into a single array (values that is) and then use `asort()`??

Comment: The best way to know what is better, is benchmark. Try and see be yourself :)

Comment: Crackertastic, I don't really need to sort. I just want to remove all units except the lowest priced unit.

Comment: I see....perhaps a combination would help.  Make a function that does a `foreach` to eliminate all but the lowest price on a single unit and then run that function through your `array_filter()` for your big array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will go through your multi-dimensional array and grab the lowest units.  It will retain the key of the big array (50, 100) and the key of the unit it grabbed (41788, 41570).  It **will not** retain multiple values of the same low rate.  In those cases it will return the first of the lowest value it found.  Might not be exactly what you want, but it should be a good start and you can always modify it later.  It uses a nested `foreach` to get its work done.

Hope this help you out!

```
function findLows($big) {
    $lowUnits = array();
    foreach($big as $id => $array) {
        $low = false;
        $prev = false;
        foreach($array as $k => $a) {
            if(!$low) {
                $low = $k;
                $prev = $a['StdRate'];
            } else {
                if($a['StdRate'] < $prev) {
                    $prev = $a['StdRate'];
                    $low = $k;
                }
            }
        }
        $lowUnits[$id] = array( $low => $array[$low]);
    }
    return $lowUnits;
}

$bigArray = array();
$bigArray[50][41788] = array('StdRate' => 231.0000, 'UnitName' => "NN23");
$bigArray[50][46238] = array('StdRate' => 303.0000, 'UnitName' => "1038");
$bigArray[50][46207] = array('StdRate' => 303.0000, 'UnitName' => "1007");
$bigArray[100][41570] = array('StdRate' => 299.0000, 'UnitName' => "HH18");
$bigArray[100][46214] = array('StdRate' => 388.0000, 'UnitName' => "1014");

$filtered = findLows($bigArray);

var_dump($filtered);
```

Will produce:

```
array(2) {
  [50]=>
  array(1) {
    [41788]=>
    array(2) {
      ["StdRate"]=>
      float(231)
      ["UnitName"]=>
      string(4) "NN23"
    }
  }
  [100]=>
  array(1) {
    [41570]=>
    array(2) {
      ["StdRate"]=>
      float(299)
      ["UnitName"]=>
      string(4) "HH18"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an array with 1 fewer levels of depth, you could have directly iterated the data with `array_filter()`.  Because you want to filter each set of data relating to first level entries, you just need to nest the `array_filter()` inside of `array_map()` (for a functional-style script).

I am going to isolate the `StdRate` values in each set and determine the lowest value by calling `min()` on the temporary array generated by `array_column()`.

To pass the `$min` value into the filter's scope, use `use()`.

This snippet will potentially return multiple deep subarrays for a respective set of data IF there is a tie among the lowest values in the set.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YlTBi))

```
$units = [
    50 => [
        41788 => ['StdRate' => 231.0000, 'UnitName' => "NN23"],
        46238 => ['StdRate' => 303.0000, 'UnitName' => "1038"],
        46207 => ['StdRate' => 303.0000, 'UnitName' => "1007"]
    ],
    100 => [
        41570 => ['StdRate' => 299.0000, 'UnitName' => "HH18"],
        46214 => ['StdRate' => 388.0000, 'UnitName' => "1014"]
    ]
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        function($unit) {
            $min = min(array_column($unit, 'StdRate'));
            return array_filter(
                $unit,
                function($row) use ($min) {
                    return $row['StdRate'] == $min;
                }
            );
        },
        $units
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  50 => 
  array (
    41788 => 
    array (
      'StdRate' => 231.0,
      'UnitName' => 'NN23',
    ),
  ),
  100 => 
  array (
    41570 => 
    array (
      'StdRate' => 299.0,
      'UnitName' => 'HH18',
    ),
  ),
)
```